# In platformer games, what are "hole in the ground" obstacles called?

Tags: 2d, platformer, side-scroller, terminology

In most jump and run games, holes in the ground are common obstacles: You need to jump over them, or you'll fall down and lose a life.

[image: Super Mario screenshot, with a pit on Mario's left]

It would be helpful to know for documentation, variable naming and discussion: **What are those holes called?**

Comment: I doubt that there's an "accepted term". Just from a word-definition perspective, I'd recommend *abyss*: A *hole* is any sort of  hollow space through an otherwise solid body, while *abyss* implies it is *downward*, as well as *in the ground* and *really, really deep and a bad idea to fall into*.

Comment: As a kid, when I played these games a lot, the word we used in German (*Abgrund*) translates to *abyss*.

Comment: Usually I'd Google to figure out if it's a commonly used term, but here I keep getting [the 1984 game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abyss_(video_game)), the [PSV *Uncharted*](http://uncharted.wikia.com/wiki/Uncharted:_Golden_Abyss), the [Tales RPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_the_Abyss), et cetera, with any relevant search query I can think of. Agh!

Comment: In most manuals it's called a pit. I don't see how this is relevant to game development? You could use bottomless pit to be more specific. For instance in the game Pitfall there are lots of pits. They aren't bottomless though. An abyss would be way to dramatic for a pit in a platformer.

Comment: @arthur it is relevant, as it could be about naming methods or classes in the code, or explaining stuff that happens in code documentation. It's important to know the name of the stuff you are talking about, or maintainers will have a very hard time understanding what's going on. I did consider asking this at Arqade, but it seemed a lot more appropriate here out of the above reasons.

Comment: In that case, please edit the question to explain this relevance and I will upvote it.

Comment: @arthus: I already did. :)

Comment: First thing i thought about was Pit, but how about cliff. In the end you decide how to call it and as long as it is clear it's fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In various *Super Mario* games, it's called a [*pit*, *abyss* or *bottomless pit*](http://www.mariowiki.com/Pit_%28obstacle%29).

*Bottomless Pit* is also a [TV trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BottomlessPits?from=Main.BottomlessPit).

Comment: Typically it's the quick stop at the end of a fall that kills you. With bottomless pits, it's the crushing air pressure.

Comment: or dehydration.

Comment: or the bordem...

Comment: or the fact that it's a video game and it doesn't have to be perfectly realistic! :P

Comment: Actually, it's the instant death trigger tile slightly below the pit that kills you. Come on, guys, we're on gamedev!

Comment: Either that or a function that checks if the Character's Y-Position is ever less than zero.

Comment: Real game developers just write the player's sprite off the end of the screen buffer and then catch the segmentation fault.

Comment: There's a reason behind the name of the old school runner: Pitfall